# Proving a group homomorphism of a cartesian product, what are the operations?

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

**Edit:** I added my own attempt at an answer after working some things out. Could anyone check if the answer I gave is correct?

I was given the following question:

> Let $G$ be a group, $N_1,N_2\triangleleft G$. Define the function $f:G\to (G/N_1)\times (G/N_2)$ by $f(a)=(aN_1, aN_2).$ Prove that $f$ is a group-homomorphism with kernel $N_1\cap N_2$.

I proceeded to try some things, but I find it hard to prove things when the operations of the groups are not given. I thought that the following would work, but the lack of concrete operations leaves me on defense:

$f(ab)=(abN_1, abN_2) = (aN_1bN_1, aN_2bN_2) = (aN_1, aN_2)(bN_1, bN_2) = f(a)f(b)$.

This would mean that some sort of product $\circ$ would be defined on $(G/N_1)\times (G/N_2)$ by $(a, b)\circ(x,y) = (ax,by)$, but again I can't really find this anywhere concretely. Is this all correct?

For the kernel part: am I looking for $N(f)=\{a\in G: f(a)=(0N_1,0N_2) = (\bar{0}, \bar{0})\}$?

Comment: That's correct.  If $H_1$ and $H_2$ are groups, there is only one reasonable way to make $H_1 \times H_2$ into a group.

Comment: Yes, that's the correct product on the Cartesian product of two groups. That's a standard definition you should be able to find in any group theory text, perhaps under the terminology "direct sum".

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers. In general I try to find the most reasonable way to create a group, but as soon as we move to cartesian products, vectors, matrices etc. sometimes you have to be a bit more careful I suppose.

Comment: Note that the problem statement does not specify the group operation on $G/N$ either. You *know* which operation is meant when the quotient by a normal subgroup is mentioned. Same for product.

Answer (score 1):

- $f$ is a group homomorphism:

  $f(ab)=(abN_1, abN_2) = (aN_1bN_1, aN_2bN_2) = (aN_1, aN_2)(bN_1, bN_2) = f(a)f(b)$.

---

- $N(f)=N_1\cap N_2$

  (1) Suppose $a\in N_1\cap N_2$, then $aN_1=N_1=\bar{e}$ and $aN_2=N_2=\bar{e}$, so that we have $f(a)=(\bar{e}, \bar{e}).$ So $a\in N(f)$ which means $N_1\cap N_2\subset N(f)$.

  (2) Suppose $a\in N(f)$, then $f(a)=(\bar{e}, \bar{e})= (N_1, N_2) = (aN_1, aN_2)$.

  Suppose that $a\in N_1\backslash N_2$, then $aN_1=\bar{e}$ but $aN_2\neq \bar{e}$ which contradicts the fact that $f(a)=(\bar{e}, \bar{e})= (N_1, N_2) = (aN_1, aN_2)$. The same contradiction follows from $a\in N_2\backslash N_1$.

  So, $a$ must be in both $N_1$ and $N_2$, which gives us $N(f)\subset N_1\cap N_2$.

  From (1) and (2) we can conclude that $N(f)=N_1\cap N_2$.

Comment: For the last part you can simply use $a\in\ker f\iff f(a)=(eN_1,eN_2)\iff aN_1=N_1\land aN_2=N_2\iff a\in N_1\land a\in N_2\iff a\in N_1\cap N_2$